# Fetching specific values from Ruby array and creating a comma-delimited string

Tags: javascript, ruby, arrays, erb

I need a bit of help with some Ruby array jujitsu.

I have the following array called @tasks:

```
[#<PivotalTracker::Story:0x007f9d6b8 @id=314, @url="http://www.pivotaltracker.com/", @created_at=#<DateTime: 2012-06-18T20:23:42+00:00 ((2456097j,73422s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, @accepted_at=nil, @project_id=357031, @name="Test ", @description="This is the description for \"Test\"", @story_type="feature", @estimate=-1, @current_state="unstarted", @requested_by="joe jones", @owned_by=nil, @labels=nil, @jira_id=nil, @jira_url=nil, @other_id=nil, @integration_id=nil, @deadline=nil, @attachments=[]>, #<PivotalTracker::Story:0x007f9d6b8 @id=315, @url="http://www.pivotaltracker.com/", @created_at=#<DateTime: 2012-06-18T20:25:20+00:00 ((2456097j,73520s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, @accepted_at=nil, @project_id=357031, @name="Test 2", @description="This is the description for \"Test 2\"", @story_type="feature", @estimate=-1, @current_state="unstarted", @requested_by="joe jones", @owned_by=nil, @labels=nil, @jira_id=nil, @jira_url=nil, @other_id=nil, @integration_id=nil, @deadline=nil, @attachments=[]>, #<PivotalTracker::Story:0x007f9d6b8 @id=316, @url="http://www.pivotaltracker.com/story/", @created_at=#<DateTime: 2012-06-18T20:25:26+00:00 ((2456097j,73526s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, @accepted_at=nil, @project_id=357031, @name="Test 3", @description="Description for Test 3 ", @story_type="feature", @estimate=-1, @current_state="unstarted", @requested_by="joe jones", @owned_by=nil, @labels=nil, @jira_id=nil, @jira_url=nil, @other_id=nil, @integration_id=nil, @deadline=nil, @attachments=[]>]
```

My end goal is to create a JavaScript array in my .erb view with just the ID values in the above array.

I was thinking of trying something like:

```
var myJSArray = [<%= @tasks.each { |t| print t.id.to_s+", " } %>];
```

However, that obviously appends a "," to the end of the string, which is not desirable (i.e. it returns "314, 315, 316,". It also seems like a bit of a hack and not the right way to do it.

Any ideas on how to do this properly?

Thank you!

UPDATE: After some more research on SO, it seems I can do this in two steps:

```
@ids = @tasks.map { |t| t.id }
```

and then use that in the view with:

```
var myJSArray = [<%= @ids.map(&:to_s).join(", ") %>];
```

Not sure if this is ideal or if it could be done in a single step, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var myJSArray = [<%= j @tasks.map(&:id).join(',') %>];
```

Or you may prefer something like this:

```
var myJSArray = <%= @tasks.map(&:id).to_json %>;
```

Comment: thanks! the first variation worked when i don't include the "j" - not sure why that is there?

Comment: When you say the first one doesn't work -- or the second one causes issues -- what actually happens? `j` is an alias for `escape_javascript`, but it's not really needed if you're sure all of your ids are integers, as your sample data shows.

Comment: @RobDavis: when using to_json, my app does not behave as expected. in the chrome browser console, when typing the array name, it displays "[> Array[3]]". i can drill-down and it displays the values there. on the other hand, the version that does not use to_json dispays "[312, 313, 314]". that version works properly for me. not sure why they both don't have the same output.

Comment: Ah, there was a typo in the answer, a dollar sign where a percent should be.

Comment: hm, is the answer corrected? it looks like the same? i don't recall seeing a $

Answer (score 1):

Use `Array#join` :

```
<%=print @task.map {|t| t.id.to_s}.join(', ') %>
```